# How to split a string via space or curly bracket?

Tags: android, string, split

I am trying to split a string by either "space" or "}".
From:

```
ApplicationInfo{14e37ebc com.android.gallery},ApplicationInfo{36e26e45 com.android.quicksearchbox},ApplicationInfo{2a60299a com.android.browser}
```

To:

```
ApplicationInfo{14e37ebc 
com.android.gallery  //after the space
},ApplicationInfo{36e26e45 
com.android.quicksearchbox  //after the space
},ApplicationInfo{2a60299a 
com.android.browser  //after the space
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do splitting according to the below regex.

```
string.split("\\s+|(?=\\})");
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/zA0bB1/1)

- `\\s+` matches one or more space characters.
- `|` OR
- `(?=\\})` match all the boundaries which exists before `}`.
- Finally the split func would do splitting according to the matches..